# mcrypt installation error mcrypt.ini.dpkg-new no such file or directory

Tags: apt, apache2, php

I'm trying to install magento in my ubuntu system. Once I installed the `php5-mcrypt` plugin successfully. But the Magento installation wizard was still showing the warning message "mcrypt is not loaded" meanwhile the `php5 -m` shows the mcrypt is already loaded. I tried some experiments like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26116530/php-extension-mcrypt-must-be-loaded) but it didn't work.

Inbetween some workarounds, I modified some `mcrypt.ini` files (don't remember what exactly I did. sorry). At some point I purged out the `php5-mcrypt` pluign. Now  the problem is that, I'm not even able to reinstall the `php5-mcrypt`. When I `'apt-get install php5-mcrypt` , it shows

> (Reading database ... 214103 files and directories currently installed.)
>   Preparing to unpack .../php5-mcrypt_5.4.6-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb ...
>   Unpacking php5-mcrypt (5.4.6-0ubuntu5) ...
>   dpkg: warning: php5-mcrypt: config file 'etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini' is a circular link
>    (= '/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini')
>   dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/php5-mcrypt_5.4.6-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb (--unpack):
>    unable to open '/etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini.dpkg-new': No such file or directory
>   No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
>            Errors were encountered while processing:
>    /var/cache/apt/archives/php5-mcrypt_5.4.6-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I tried even after re installing php and all other components as in [this tutorial](http://davidtsadler.com/archives/2012/06/03/how-to-install-magento-on-ubuntu/#start) but still same problem exist. I'm not able to figure out the issue. I'm using ubuntu 14.04. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini and /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini in case any of them still exist and then try installing it again with apt-get

```
sudo rm -f /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini

sudo rm -f /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
```

The problem should be coming from the first file, but delete the second one as well just to be sure.

Comment: Good to hear :)